# Unusual exception.Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate

I met this exception with springboot 1.5.3 + hibernate5. 
And ,i used the `@EnableTransactionManagement` at the start application class. Have the transaction aop configuration as follow code...

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class TransactionManagerConfig {
private static final String AOP_POINTCUT_EXPRESSION="execution (* *..service..*Service*.*(..))";
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("transactionManager")
        private HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager;
......
......
```

It worked very nice until yestardy.And then,i create a service named c.a.b.service.MessageCoreService.

```
@Service
public class MessageCoreService {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSourceResolverMapper mapper;
    @Autowired
    private TenantIdentifierResolver tir;
    public Map<String, MsgDetail> fetchCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        System.err.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() at MessageCoreService:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.err.println("request teanantId:" + tir.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier());

        System.err.println("locale3 at MessageCoreService:" + locale.toString());
        MsgDetail enMsg = mapper.resolveCode(code, MessageSourceResolver.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
        MsgDetail localeMsg = mapper.resolveCode(code, locale.toString());
        Map<String, MsgDetail> ret = new HashMap<String, MsgDetail>();
        ret.put("defaultLocale", enMsg);
        ret.put("requestLocale", localeMsg);
        return ret;
    }
```

In the controller, do a test first.

```
    @Autowired
private MessageCoreService msgService;
@RequestMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, MsgDetail> test() {
    System.err.println("111111111111111111111111111111111:");
    TenantIdentifierResolver.tempOverideTenantId(ZAppUtils.getInitDatabaseId()); // change to init database
    ServiceResult<Module> rslt = new ServiceResult<Module>();
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    System.err.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() at ResourcesModuleController:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.err.println("request teanantId:" + tir.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier());
    return msgService.fetchCode("e90001.5", locale);
```

Then, the hibernate exception "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" occured.

I checked over and over,everything is ok.But it's aways occured.
I don't understand any of this. And then,i coped c.a.b.service.MessageCoreService. to c.a.c.service.MessageAdminService. Yes,just change a direcory,rename it.
In the controller,add a method.

```
   @Autowired
private MessageCoreAdminService msgAdminService;
@RequestMapping("/test2")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, MsgDetail> test2() {
    System.err.println("111111111111111111111111111111111:");
    TenantIdentifierResolver.tempOverideTenantId(ZAppUtils.getInitDatabaseId()); // change to init database
    ServiceResult<Module> rslt = new ServiceResult<Module>();
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    System.err.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() at ResourcesModuleController:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return msgAdminService.fetchCode("e90001.5", locale);
}
```

And then ,an incredible scene appeared. When i access the test2,it worked normally, but the test method ,it still show me the "transaction-synchronized Session" exception. Oh ,I feel like I'm breaking down. I can't resolve the problem.
Pls help.